# tooltip jquery always present

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code (http://jsfiddle.net/56bv52us/3/):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<input class="age" title="Hello <br/>My message" >

<script>
$(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip({
        content: function() {
            return $(this).attr('title');
        }
    });
});     

</script>
```

What I am trying to do is the message always appear, ie, no need to move the mouse over to the message appears, it is always present. You can do this without affecting the HTML in the message?

I am using this toolkip: http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: you link is not working

Comment: `    $('[title]').tooltip({
        content: function () {
            return $(this).attr('title');
        }
    });
` You should use this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target the element and call the [open method](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#event-open)

```js
$(function() {
  $('input.age').mouseleave(function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }).tooltip({
    content: function() {
      return $(this).attr('title');
    }
  }).tooltip('open')
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input class="age" title="Hello <br/>My message">
```

Comment: @ArunPJohny , Why does this works? I thought mouseleave event is fired when the cursor is above the element and leaves it. Thank you

Comment: @pablito.aven the mouseleave is used to prevent the hiding of tooltip when you leave the element after hovering it

Comment: @ArunPJohny but why does it fires on page load without hovering the element?

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(".age").trigger("mouseover");
```

*note: this will only work until hovered